# Adjoints between the category of sets and the category of left G-sets.

Tags: category-theory, group-actions, adjoint-functors

What functors are there between the category Set and the category of left G sets? Of these functors can you show which are adjoints?

Bonus points for leading this question,  and me, in a  more rigorous direction.

Comment: At least, there is the forgetful functor from $G$-Sets to Sets.

Comment: That one I managed: it's the others that confuse me.

Comment: You may think of the following functors from $G$-Sets to Sets: $A\mapsto G\times A$, $A\mapsto A^G$. From Sets to $G$-Sets : $A\mapsto A'$ where $A'$ is the set $A$ endowed with the trivial action of $G$ ($\forall (g,a)\in G\times A,\;g.a=a$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The forgetful functor from $G$-sets to sets has adjoints on both sides.  The left adjoint sends any set $A$ to the product $G\times A$ with the $G$-action defined by $g(h,a)=(gh,a)$ (for all $g,h\in G$ and $a\in A$). This should be called the free $G$-set generated by $A$.  The right adjoint sends $A$ to the set of all functions from $G$ to $A$ (just set-theoretic functions, ignoring the group structure of $G$) with the $G$-action defined by $(gf)(h)=f(hg)$ for all $g,h\in G$ and all functions $f:G\to A$.

Comment: Hrm. Don't you want $(g \cdot f)(h) = f(g^{-1}h)$ instead, so that you get a $G$-set homomorphism $A^G \times G \to A : (f,g) \mapsto f(g)$ (with the trivial action on $A$)?

Comment: @Hurkyl It seems that your version of this functor and mine are naturally isomorphic.  The isomorphism sends (in both directions) a function $f:G\to A$ to the function $\hat f:G\to A$ defined by $\hat f(x)=f(x^{-1})$. Since adjoints are unique only up to natural isomorphism, either version is correct.  Yours has, as you noted, a nicer formula for the evaluation map.  Mine seems to arise more immediately from a direct calculation of the adjoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has a certain clarity to it. I did want to ask how one would spot such adjoints; they seem fine once explained but evidently I struggle to find them on my own.

Comment: @East I'm not sure I have a good answer for how to find such adjoints. I knew about this example because, years ago, I spent considerable time thinking about permutation actions of groups, originally motivated by topos theory, where group actions provide some nice examples. On the other hand, a really abstract explanation of how to find examples like this is that they're a special case of the general notion of Kan extension.

Comment: @East There are a couple of general ideas that can be helpful. First, in algebraic situations, forgetful functors tend to have left adjoints given by free constructions. The $G\times A$ in my answer is a $G$-set freely generated by the elements of $A$.  Second, right adjoints become easy to find when the underlying set functor on your category is representable. For $G$-sets, the representing object is $G$ itself (acting on itself by left multiplication). So if $R$ is right adjoint to $L$ then the underlying set of $R(X)$ is $\text{Hom}(G,R(X))=\text{Hom}(L(G),X)$.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant functors out of $G$-sets are the fixed point functor, which has been mentioned in comments, and the orbit functor $X\mapsto X/G$, which has not. One can generalize these to the fixed points or orbits with respect to any subgroup. The orbit functor is left adjoint to the free $G$-set functor, while fixed points are right adjoint to the trivial $G$-set functor. This becomes less muddled when one observes that the forgetful functor is simply fixed points for the trivial subgroup, and that the trivial $G$-set on $S$ is (essentially) just the free trivial group action on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Going from G-sets to sets represents a loss of structure. This is the nature behind the forgetful functor designation; it "forgets" what it means to be "G" and only remembers what it means to be "-set".

And in an example of duality, in G-sets this functor has an opposite. And while the conventional way of thinking about opposites is in terms of a forward and backward, positive and negative,  I suggest to you that in category theory it's more fruitful to think of these adjoints as "doing" and "undoing"

As such, if in one direction this adjunction represents a loss of structure (the doing) then going in the other direction must represent a gain in structure (undoing that loss).

The gain in structure that compliments a forgetful loss is known as the **FREE FUNCTOR**.

The idea behind the free functor is that in going in the opposite direction, from sets to G-sets, you only add the minimal amount of structure to uniquely identify a G-set from any other set in your theory. This is known as a free construction since it is "free" of any superfluous structure except for "G".

(PS: As a comment
 made clear, this is NOT true of all categories, i.e., not all categories with a forgetful functor have a free functor)

Comment: Geez, the balance between freewheeling philosophizing and precise mathematics might be a bit off here. I don't see how to interpret "by categorical duality..." in a way that wouldn't imply that every functor, at least every faithful functor, has a left adjoint.

Comment: Here we are talking specifically about G-Sets which does admit a free functor.  We are not talking about "every" category, such as Top which doesn't.  I'll try and tidy up the "categorical duality" bit to make that clearer, thanks!